# In Ionic 2, how do you "zoom out" of your emulation that is too big to fit on your screen?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I ran `ionic emulate ios` with an iPad-Air image which is too big to fit on my laptop. Is there a way to "shrink" it. Currently it's making me scroll up and down.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Mac OS Simulator? If yes, type cmd + 2 or cmd + 3 to reduce window size.